# Read text file as bytes, split on a character

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to process large records in Hadoop that span multiple lines. Each records consists of this:

```
>record_id|record_name                    // Should be the key
JAKSJDUVUAKKSKJJDJBUUBLAKSJDJUBKAKSJSDJB  // Should be the value
KSJGFJJASPAKJWNMFKASKLSKJHUUBNFNNAKSLKJD
JDKSKSKALSLDKSDKPBPBPKASJDKSALLKSADJSAKD
```

I want to read the file containing these records as bytes because reading it as a String is just too memory intensive, as a single record can be well over 100MB. **I cannot split these records** on anything but the `>` character that defines a new record in the file.

I've been looking for a default `RecordReader` and `InputFormat` that can do these steps for me, but I haven't been able to find it. I'm trying to write my own. But I have no examples/tutorials to follow on this subject.

How should I approach this?